# Display System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView new Record row at the top instead of bottom?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When you use the `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` and set the `AllowUserToAddRows` property to true, it displays a blank row at the bottom of the grid which users can use to add new rows to the grid.  I want this row to display at the top of the grid instead of at the bottom, but cannot figure out how to do that.  I found [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka3w9f4d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which says

> The DataGridView control supports this functionality by providing a row for new records, which is always shown as the last row.

So I'm not sure if it's actually possible to have it display at the first row, but thought I'd ask anyways. My DataGridView is data bound if that makes a difference.

---

Update

It looks like it's not possible to have the "new row" show at the top of the grid, so what I did instead was changed my columns to sort descending, rather than ascending, and programmatically scroll the data grid view to the bottom of the list when the form is loaded. Not the ideal solution I was looking for, but it's the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AllowUserToAddRows, you could instead create an "Add row" button.  When the button is clicked, it programmatically inserts a row at index 0 using code such as:

```
myDgv.Rows.Insert(0,1)
```